# Convert columns with time format HHMMSS to sec

Tags: python, pandas

I have a very long pandas dataframe (10000s of rows). In one column the time is stored in the following format: 'HHMMSS'.

For my further calculation I need to add beside this column a column with seconds.

Here is my problem, described with an example pandas dataframe with 3 rows and 1 column.

```
import pandas as pd

data = [['123455'], ['000010'], ['100000']]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['HHMMSS'])

print(df)

#   HHMMSS
#0  123455
#1  000010
#2  100000

def get_seconds(time_str):
    hh, mm, ss = time_str[0:2], time_str[2:4], time_str[4:6]
    return int(hh) * 3600 + int(mm) * 60 + int(ss)

sec=[get_seconds(df['HHMMSS'][0]),get_seconds(df['HHMMSS'][1]),get_seconds(df['HHMMSS'][2])]

df['sec']=sec

print(df)

#   HHMMSS    sec
#0  123455  45295
#1  000010     10
#2  100000  36000
```

How would a (performant) solution look like for very long dataframes?

Comment: Is `123465` a typo? Shouldn't it be `123456` (56 instead of 65)

Comment: :-) yes this is stupid, changed from 123465 to 123455

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[pandas.Series.dt.total_seconds()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.total_seconds.html) only works on TimedeltaArray, TimedeltaIndex or on Series containing timedelta values under the `.dt` namespace.

Since your value doens't have any separator among values, you need to use `format` argument to let pandas know the format. Then convert it to timedelta values with `pd.to_timedelta()`. At last use the `dt.total_seconds()` property to get total seconds of timedelta.

```py
df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['HHMMSS'], format='%H%M%S')
df['delta'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['datetime'].dt.strftime('%H:%M:%S'))
df['delta'].dt.total_seconds()
```

Answer (score 0):

`print(df['col'].dt.total_seconds())` should work.

You may need to set the column to a date time value first, to do this:

```
df['col'] = pd.to_datetime(df['col'])
df['col'].dt.total_seconds()
```

Comment: Your answer looks like a duplicate to the accepted answer. Please provide more explanation of what you are trying to add.